# How to set (0, 0) coordinate position for GLFW window

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, window, glfw

I'm creating a GLFW window, and I would like the bottom left corner to be the origin. For some reason, the top left corner is the origin.

I should also mention that I'm using OSX.

Here's my window class:

```
#include "window.h"

namespace graphics {
    void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
    void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
    void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mode);
    void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double mouse_x, double mouse_y);
    Window::Window(const char* title, int width, int height) {
        m_title = title;
        m_width = width;
        m_height = height;
        if (!init())
            glfwTerminate();
    }
    Window::~Window() {
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    bool Window::init() {
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            std::cout << "GLFW failed to initialize!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
        m_window = glfwCreateWindow(m_width, m_height, m_title, NULL, NULL);
        if (!m_window) {
            glfwTerminate();
            std::cout << "GLFW failed to create a window!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
        glfwSetWindowUserPointer(m_window, this);
        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_window, window_size_callback);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(m_window, key_callback);
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(m_window, mouse_button_callback);
        glfwSetCursorPosCallback(m_window, cursor_position_callback);
        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
            std::cout << "GLEW failed to initialize!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        std::cout << "OpenGL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "OpenGL Shading Language Version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    void Window::update() {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(m_window);
    }
    void Window::clear() const {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    bool Window::isClosed() const {
        return glfwWindowShouldClose(m_window);
    }
    bool Window::isKeyPressed(unsigned int keycode) const {
        if (keycode >= MAX_KEYS)
            return false;
        return m_keys[keycode];
    }
    bool Window::isMouseButtonPressed(unsigned int button) const {
        if (button >= MAX_BUTTONS)
            return false;
        return m_mouse_buttons[button];
    }
    void Window::getMousePosition(double& x, double& y) const {
        x = m_mouse_x;
        y = m_mouse_y;
    }
    void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
        Window* win = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
        win->m_width = width;
        win->m_height = height;
    }
    void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) {
        Window* win = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
        win->m_keys[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
    }
    void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mode) {
        Window* win = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
        win->m_mouse_buttons[button] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
    }
    void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double mouse_x, double mouse_y) {
        Window* win = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
        win->m_mouse_x = mouse_x;
        win->m_mouse_y = mouse_y;
    }
}
```

Comment: The origin for what?  Mouse coordinates?

Comment: That and opengl. @genpfault

Answer (score -1):

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

> But here is a better way to visualize this : use the Right Hand Rule
>
> - X is your thumb
> - Y is your index
> - Z is your middle finger. If you put
>
> your thumb to the right and your index to the sky, it will point to
>   your back, too. Having the Z in this direction is weird, so why is it
>   so ? Short answer : because 100 years of Right Hand Rule Math will
>   give you lots of useful tools. The only downside is an unintuitive Z.
>
> **This is something you can’t change**, it’s built in your graphics card.
>   So (-1,-1) is the bottom left corner of your screen. (1,-1) is the
>   bottom right, and (0,1) is the middle top. So this triangle should
>   take most of the screen.

Comment: The origin is only hard coded in NDC. If you apply, for example, a y-axis mirroring after the projection, then everything will behave as if the origin is the top-left corner. Just keep in mind that mirroring changes the polygon winding order.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? OpenGL uses the coordinate system they want. They're talking about setting the window origin to the *bottom left*, the way it is in OpenGL. Instead, window coordinates have the origin in the *top left*, so that corner is 0,0.